# Delphi: Delphi and Microsoft SQL Server 2005 bad calculations from function values

Tags: sql-server-2005, delphi, string, decimal

When i send this query on SQL Server 2005 with the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

```
SELECT dbo.MOV('Hi',10,2) + dbo.MOV('Hi2',8,2)
```

The query returns 400

The result of anything send to the function will return 200 except if the last two
parameter where 0 the value of return will be 100 and the value type of return from the function its Decimal(12,2)

the problem, comes when I do the query on Delphi

```
Query.SQL.Add('SELECT dbo.MOV(''Hi'',10,2) + dbo.MOV(''Hi2'',8,2)');
Query.Open;
Query.Next;
ShowMessage(Query.Fields[0].AsString);
```

The Query returns 200 (on the message dialog), like if SQL Server is just taking the first Function and ignoring the second one, so what i could do get from SQL Server 2005 the right calculation in Delphi. Thanks.

Comment: Why you are using a `Query.Next;` after `Query.Open;`? the `Next` call is not necessary when you retrieve a single record result. remember when you execute the `open` procedure the returned `Dataset` is ready to be read.

Comment: I'd start with `Query.SQL.Clear`, to be on the safe side. Then I'd try selecting just the first half, then the second half, and inspecting the results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to clear Query.SQL before Query.SQL.Add.

```
Query.SQL.Clear
Query.SQL.Add('SELECT dbo.MOV(''Hi'',10,2) + dbo.MOV(''Hi2'',8,2)');
```

If you already have a query stored in SQL you will only see the result from the first one.

Comment: This was the problem, I didn't used the Clear Statement before adding the SQL Sentence, Thank you so much.