# How to control the order of Fields in TQuery

Tags: delphi

I am using Delphi 7. `TQuery` connected to Firebird DB.

Table T1 has 3 fields (A, B, and C).

To query that table, I wrote the following code:

```
MyQuery.SQL.Clear;
MyQuery.SQL.Add('SELECT B, C, A FROM T1'); // because that's the order I want them
MyQuery.Open;
```

However, when filling a string grid's top row with `FieldNames` (by iterating through the `Fields[]` array) I don't want to have to rely on static fieldname to column mapping, but my problem is that the order of fields in the `Fields[]` array doesn't match the order of the fields in the SQL I used.

**EDIT**

I'm using one routine for multiple reports with different SQLs at *runtime*. I don't want to rely on `FieldNames` at all, so I need to make the `TQuery.Fields` array sorted in the order of the fields appearing in the SQL in `TQuery.SQL` (at *runtime*).

My question is: how can I control the order of the Fields in `MyQuery.Fields[]` so that it matches the order I used in the SQL? Is there a better alternative that I should try?

**EDIT**

Sorry, it was just a silly bug in the end. One too many `SQL.Clear`!

Comment: Probably MyQuery has persistent fields in the order that you get.

Comment: Persistent fields being what you get when double click the query component and then add fields using the dialog that comes up.

Comment: what do you mean you don't want to rely on FieldNames at all. You don't want your grid columns to get the names from the SQL columns? There's SQL syntax that can help you if that's what you're doing.

Comment: Sorry Guys, found the bug... one too many SQL.Clear (how ironic considering @Cosmin's answer :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, this:

```
MyQuery.SQL.Add('SELECT B, C, A FROM T1');
```

should be:

```
MyQuery.SQL.Text := 'SELECT B, C, A FROM T1';
```

or:

```
MyQuery.SQL.Clear;
MyQuery.SQL.Add('SELECT B, C, A FROM T1');
```

because `Add()` alone appends something to the existing query in `MyQuery.SQL`. In that case the behavior would be provider-dependent. With some providers you simply get the first query executed and the other ones ignored, while with other providers you'd get an error. Either way it's wrong.

If that still doesn't fix it, what `Query` are you talking about, what kind of database and what kind of grid? The behavior might be database-dependent or grid-dependent; For what it's worth, I've never seen it happen before, I always got the columns in SQL order. But I'm mostly using Firebird, MsSQL, a little Oracle.

Comment: Provider remark is not factually correct, no DBMS treat `newline` as statement separator, it is valid statement "token" (not really a token but whitespace which is part of **single** statement). Also OP said he's populating TStringGrid instance from returned cursor.

Comment: Sorry @Cosmin, the type of "Query" is in the question text ("TQuery"). I'm afraid you missed it. And I know to .Clear before .Add, it's just that it has nothing to do with my question regarding the order of fields in TQuery.Fields[] so I left it out intentionally along with the "uses" clause and the "begin" and the "end". I agree, most of the time you get the columns according to the way they're specified in the query.

Comment: It's connected to a Firebird db, but I honestly doubt that has any influence on the workings of TQuery.

Comment: @user, a `"string grid"` isn't necessary a `TStringGrid`. And here's [a link showing one case where SQL was returning bogus data because of forgotten Clear](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216227/delphi-delphi-and-microsoft-sql-server-2005-bad-calculations-from-function-value).

Comment: @Sam, Firebird returns fields in the order specified in the SQL statement. In that case Branko might be onto something. If your Query has persisted fields, it will ignore runtime fields. Just make sure you don't have persisted fields.

Comment: Ironically it was one too many .Clear that had compromised one of the queries. Thought it was interesting, didn't turn out that way. You were on the right track. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

DataSet's Fields collection items can be rearranged in Fields Editor that you can access from mouse right-click menu on the TQuery component.